# What do bioconda's perl-net-ftp and perl-lwp-protocol-https do?

Tags: http, ftp, dependencies, conda, snakemake

I was given some code of a previous intern and I'm supposed to find out what it does.

It is a snakemake pipeline that has a `my_pipeline.yaml` file which is supposed to contain all the 'general packages needed for the pipeline'
The file looks like this:

```
name: my_pipeline

channels:
    - conda-forge
    - bioconda

dependencies:
    - snakemake
    - perl-net-ftp
    - perl-lwp-protocol-https
```

I googled both `perl-net-ftp` and `perl-lwp-protocol-https` but I was unable to find docs on them.

All I can gather from my limited understanding as a newbie: ftp stands for ["file transfer protocol"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_Transfer_Protocol) and I definitely heard that sometime before, perl is a language (that I don't know). [HTTPS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTPS) is another protocol, sure...

Regarding the `perl-net-ftp` I even found the [bioconda link](https://anaconda.org/bioconda/perl-net-ftp) but the description is unfortunately empty.

Same goes for the [perl-lwp-protocol-https](https://anaconda.org/bioconda/perl-lwp-protocol-https) - the description on conda is blank.

In I see that the pipeline is using `wget` in the `snakefile`. Is it safe to assume that the 2 packages are needed inorder to run `wget`?

I'd be glad for an explanation for a beginner and of course documentation if your queries get better results.

https://anaconda.org/bioconda/perl-net-ftp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For Bioconda packages, it is usually better to look at [the Bioconda Package Index](http://bioconda.github.io/conda-package_index.html) rather than Anaconda Cloud (though admittedly the metadata here could be improved). Visiting the Bioconda pages for the perl-lwp-protocol-https and perl-net-ftp packages will lead to links to their respective upstream description pages.

| Bioconda Page | Meta::CPAN Page |
| --- | --- |
| [perl-lwp-protocol-https](http://bioconda.github.io/recipes/perl-lwp-protocol-https/README.html#package-perl-lwp-protocol-https) | [LWP::Protocol::https](https://metacpan.org/pod/LWP::Protocol::https) |
| [perl-net-ftp](http://bioconda.github.io/recipes/perl-net-ftp/README.html#package-perl-net-ftp) | [Net::FTP](https://metacpan.org/pod/Net::FTP) |

Broadly, these are Perl modules that implement functions to communicate with remote servers, which usually means downloading or uploading files in the context of a Perl script.

`wget` does not depend on Perl or those modules. So, it is still unclear the particular purpose of those. Maybe don't rule out the possibility that they aren't actually needed - sometimes people start writing things one way and then forget to remove components that they no longer require.

Comment: "don't rule out the possibility that they aren't actually needed" - That is exactly what I am trying to find out. Thanks a lot!